# Google Calendar API key is not working

Tags: zend-framework, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

So accessing from here: https://console.developers.google.com/project

In my project, I just enabled the Calendar API.

Now I am trying to do the following: (my key hidden for obvious reasons)

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/events');
$client->setParameterGet(array(
    'key' => '########################',
));
$feed = $client->request()->getBody();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($feed);
exit;
```

But doing that gives me the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using a Server API Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The calendar ID must be urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I had similar problem. Check your calendar ID in www.google.com/calendar/ -> my calendar -> calendar settings and calendar address. Id should contain letters and numbers, not email address.